# How to get all logs from an ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-ecs

Is there some AWS command get to get logs from all services/tasks from an ECS cluster? something like:

```
aws ecs logs --cluster dev
```

or

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --cluster dev logs
```

for example, there must be some API to retrieve the logs that are shown in the UI here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no such out of the box option that takes logs from all service based on the cluster, as evey container running in their own space (EC2 instance).

So there can similar option that you can try, but before that, you need to understand the logging mechanism of AWS ECS.

**logDriver**

> The log driver to use for the container. The valid values listed for
>   this parameter are log drivers that the Amazon ECS container agent can
>   communicate with by default.

For tasks using the Fargate launch type, the supported log drivers are `awslogs, splunk, and awsfirelens.`

For tasks using the EC2 launch type, the supported log drivers are `awslogs, fluentd, gelf, json-file, journald, logentries, syslog, splunk, and awsfirelens`.

So if you are running multiple container on same ec2 instance then syslog make sense for you.

**Syslog logging driver**

> The syslog logging driver routes logs to a syslog server. The syslog
>   protocol uses a raw string as the log message and supports a limited
>   set of metadata. The syslog message must be formatted in a specific
>   way to be valid. From a valid message, the receiver can extract the
>   following information:
>   [image]

But the best approach is to have a single log group against each container. as **syslog** is not working in case of fargate so better to go with log group per container.

[image]

Comment: I updated the OP, there really is no API to retrieve the logs that are available from the AWS web console?

Comment: thanks again, just as a concept, I am playing with this if you have any thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001832/how-bad-is-it-to-pipe-process-to-consumer-in-entrypoint