# How bad is it to pipe process to consumer in ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, docker-run

How bad would it be to use something like this in a Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT node . | tee >(send_logs_to_elastic_search)
```

most of the logging solutions require some pretty nasty configuration. The above would be a way for us to capture the logs programmatically and write our own glue code.

The main problem with the above solution is that `CMD` arguments would not append to the `node` process? I assume they would get append to the `tee` process instead? something like this:

```
docker run foo --arg1 --arg2
```

I assume that would then look like:

```
node . | tee >(send_logs_to_elastic_search) --arg1 --arg2
```

anybody know?

The other potentially problem is that your container is less configurable it's "hardcoded" to send the logs to the `send_logs_to_elastic_search` process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) indicates that if you use the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` then `CMD` is completely ignored.  If it weren't, then the `CMD` would be appended in essentially the way you show.

If this is just about logging, I'd recommend [setting up a Docker logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) over trying to configure logging inside the container.  This simplifies your image setup (it only needs the application and not every possible log target).  Both [logstash](https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash) and [fluentd](https://hub.docker.com/_/fluentd) are popular tools for just moving log messages around.

If you're looking at more complicated scripting, I would almost always write this into a standalone shell script, rather than trying to write it directly into the Dockerfile.

```sh
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["node", "."]
```

The entrypoint script will receive the command part as command-line arguments.  Typically it would end with `exec "$@"` to just run that command.  If you're willing to let the shell wrapper be the main container process, you could pipe the command's output somewhere

```sh
#!/bin/sh
"$@" | send_logs_to_elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your containers?

Typically you can connect filebeats, or something else directly to `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.json.log` and have the host send all the logs for all the containers

Here is a tutorial for [filebeats](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-container-log-analysis-with-elastic-stack-53d5ec9e5953/) which is nice as they do a volume mount and do the log extract with another container

Comment: see that sounds complicated to me, but I will read the link thanks

Comment: Mayb,  but its a generic solution for all your containers and is a good use of microservices. One day you might splunk instead and then its one container to migtate