# Is there any way to stream CloudWatch Metrics to a Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

One can subscribe a lambda to a CloudWatch log group,  and the new log entries will be streamed to that lambda. Is there a way to do the same for metrics?

E.x. I want to stream CPU Utilization of a certain instance to a lambda for further processing (e.g. sending it to an elasticsearch domain).

I haven't found any way of doing it as of yet.

Comment: Can you please tell us more about what you want to do? Do you want Lambda to look at _every single metric_, or just at aggregated metrics? Can you give us an example of how it would use this information?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein second paragraph of my question gives such an example - CPU utilization of an EC2 instance. I want to collect it and send to an elasticsearch domain, so that i can show cpu utilization in a Kibana graph later on

Comment: You could extract CloudWatch Metrics on a regular basis and load it into Elasticsearch. The only thing that can be "triggered" by CloudWatch Metrics is an alarm. Alternatively, you could put your own code on the EC2 instance that measures CPU and sends it directly to Elasticsearch (instead of going via CloudWatch).

Comment: Yeah, I started doing just that - having the lambda call getMetricsStatistics on the metrics I need. I was just wondering if there is a way to subscribe metrics to a lambda (doing push instead of pull) but looks like there's none.

Comment: run aws logagent to stream log to loggroup then  to push streamt to lambda then ELK,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089289/how-to-choose-different-lambda-function-while-start-streaming-to-amazon-elastics

Comment: @adiii - as i stated in the question, i'm interested in a way to stream Cloudwatch metrics, not logs